# Rooted Binary Tree - Chain Nodes Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, binary-search-trees

The question is that I have to give a recursive algorithm in pseudocode, that counts the number of chain node in a rooted binary tree. Chain node is defined as a node that has only one child and that child is not a leaf.
I am stuck any help would be appreciated, so far I have done this:

```
Algorithm Chainnode(x) {
    if (not Leaf(x)) and (left[x] XOR right[x] == Null) {
        return True
    }
    else {
        return False
    }
}

Algorithm ChainnodeCount(x) {
    i = 0
    if (x == Null or Leaf[x]) then {
        return i
    }
    else if ChainNode(left[x]) == True {
        i = ChainNodeCount(left[x]) + 1
    }   
    else if ChainNode(right[x]) == True {
        i = ChainNodeCount(right[x]) + 1
    }
    else {
        i = ChainNodeCount(left[x]) + ChainNodeCount(right[x])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of chain nodes of a rooted binary tree with two non-empty sons is the sum of the chain nodes in its sons.

Also, the number of chain nodes of a rooted binary tree with only one non-empty son is the number of chain nodes of the son plus one.

If a rooted binary tree has no non-empty sons, its number of chain nodes is zero.

And finally, the number of chain nodes of an empty rooted binary tree is zero.

So, following this properties we have

```
int chainNodes(tree T) {
    if (T is empty)
        return 0;
    if (T has no nonempty sons)
        return 0;
    if (T has only one nonempty son)
        return chainNodes(son)+1;
    if (T has two nonempty sons)
        return chainNoodes(leftSon)+chainNodes(rightSon);
}
```

which is similar to your try.